# Разбить HDD в RAID1 на 2 раздела

Tags: linux, raid

На сервере настроен *RAID1* из 4 дисков: `2x256G` и `2x1000G`:

```
    NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1      8:1    0     2G  0 part
│ └─md1     9:1    0     2G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2      8:2    0   256M  0 part
│ └─md0     9:0    0   256M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3      8:3    0 236.2G  0 part
  └─md2     9:2    0 236.1G  0 raid1 /
sdb         8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1      8:17   0     2G  0 part
│ └─md1     9:1    0     2G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2      8:18   0   256M  0 part
│ └─md0     9:0    0   256M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3      8:19   0 236.2G  0 part
  └─md2     9:2    0 236.1G  0 raid1 /
sdc         8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1      8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0 931.4G  0 raid1
sdd         8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1      8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
  └─md127   9:127  0 931.4G  0 raid1
```

Нужно разбить диск `1000G` на 2 раздела (физически это 2 диска `sdc` и `sdd`).

Какой порядок действий должен быть?

1. Разбить `sdc` на 2 раздела и это через *RAID* автоматически распространится на `sdd`.
2. Или нужно разбить *RAID1*, потом разбить `sdc` на 2 раздела и заново собрать RAID1?
3. Как то по другому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по листингу `lsblk` вы никак не используете md127 и, вероятно, данных там нет. Поэтому проще всего будет остановить этот массив

```
mdadm -S /dev/md127
```

Затем переразбить sdc и sdd как вам нравится, затем собрать raid - один или несколько, в зависимости от целей и задач.

---

Возможно, на самом деле вам нужен LVM поверх raid.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне правда кажется странным, что нужно оба диска разбивать на разделы по отдельности, когда идея RAID1 подразумевает зеркалирование дисков. Разве данные разметки sdc не должны также зеркалироваться на sdd?

Comment: mdadm делает raid из того что ему сказали. И зеркалирует то, что записано в блочное устройство самого mdadm - /dev/mdN. Поскольку у вас таблица разделов вне устройства mdadm - то она, конечно, не зеркалируется. Это в сравнении с аппаратным рейдом чуть неудобно, но есть и преимущества в гибкости. Например, можно диски порезать на два раздела, поверх sdc1 сделать raid1, поверх sdc2 сделать raid0 под рабочие данные, которые дублировать не нужно, а вот побольше свободного места хорошо.